# Window Icon of Exe in PyQt4

Tags: python, windows, qt, qt4, py2exe

I have a small program in PyQt4 and I want to compile the program into an Exe. I am using py2exe to do that. I can successfully set icon in the windows title bar using the following code, but when i compile it into exe the icon is lost and i see the default windows application. here is my program:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Icon(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('c:/python26_/repy26/icons/iqor1.ico'))


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
icon = Icon()
icon.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**** Here is the setup.py for py2exe****

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=[{"script":"iconqt.py"
               ,"icon_resources": [(1, "Iqor1.ico")]}]
                   ,options={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip", "PyQt4.QtCore"]}})
```

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that py2exe doesn't include the qt icon reader plugin.  You need to tell it to include it with the data_files parameter.  Something along these lines:

```
setup(windows=[{"script":script_path,
                "icon_resources":[(1, icon_path)]}], 
      data_files = [
            ('imageformats', [
              r'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qico4.dll'
              ])],
      options={"py2exe":{"packages":["gzip"], 
                         "includes":["sip"]}})
```

Comment: Just perfect. Exactly solve my problem. Ps this trick works for PySide too.

Comment: I have a similar setup, but it's not working. Would you mind taking a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687347/win7-taskbar-icon-incorrect-for-pyside-py2exe-app

Comment: What would you have to change to make this work with options -> bundle_files set to 1?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to reference the `.ico` file directly from the EXE or DLL that you are creating with `py2exe`.  You seem to have the setup.py script correct, so take a look at: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons.  There is an example for wxWidgets, but you could try to adapt it to Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a file called YourApp.rc, add up the following line :

```
IDI_ICON1   ICON    DISCARDABLE "res/icons/app_icon.ico"
```

Then in your .PRO file, add up the following lines :

```
win32{
RC_FILE = YourApp.rc
}
```

It should fix your problem !

Comment: What .PRO file? Py2exe uses setup.py. This answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I thought they used the same process as it is in C++. The last part of your comment is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For some reason it worked just fine with a image.png file & not an image.ico file. No clue why. But i converted the ico to png & it worked